# Use WebBrowser Navigate2 method without additional parameters in .Net

Tags: .net, browser

I have VB6 application that uses Navigate2 method of WebBrowser control. 
.Net version of WebBrowser have 8 versions of Navigate method.

Which method is mapping functionality of Navigate2 of the code below:

```
Dim url
url = "www.apple.com"
WB.Navigate2 url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [overload that takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx), like this:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://apple.com")
```

Comment: Does it means that .net version of the control is using Navigate2 by default?